# Could not verify the provided CSRF token. Using only xml

Tags: java, spring

I'm in the process of learning Spring framework, and I'm using xml configuration file for the security:

```
<security:http once-per-request="false" use-expressions="true">
    <!-- <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')" /> -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createoffer" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreateoffer" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offercreated" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll" />     
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loggedout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountcreated" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offers" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/loggedout" logout-url="/logout"/>
    <security:remember-me key="offersAppKey"
        user-service-ref="jdbcUserService"
        remember-me-parameter="remember-me" token-validity-seconds="1209600" />
</security:http>
```

and in my login form:

```
<form name='f' action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login'
    method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Remember Me</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember-me" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </table>
</form>
```

But after I log in and some time passes (I set the session timeout to be 1 minute in the `web.xml`) I get this error in the browser:

`Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.`

So far, I couldn't find any post that only uses the xml file for the configuration. It's all about configuring using java and some other answers suggest that to include `csrf` hidden input in the login form, which I already do. Any idea how to fix this issue ?

P.S.: the web.xml file looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-tutorial-51</display-name>
  <description>Spring tutorial web app</description>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/springtutorial</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/myproject/spring/web/config/dao-context.xml
        classpath:com/myproject/spring/web/config/service-context.xml
        classpath:com/myproject/spring/web/config/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>`

I added the following config to my security config file.

I added this to my `security-context.xml` which is a config file for security.

```
<security:remember-me key="offersAppKey"
user-service-ref="jdbcUserService"
remember-me-parameter="remember-me" token-validity-seconds="1209600" />
```

And I expect to have the token valid after 1 minute for 1209600 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand where is the suprising part here? You said that

> I set the session timeout to be 1 minute in the web.xml

Where else the server can store its copy of your CSRF-token except for your session? So when in a minute your session expires, the server can't find its copy to match CSRF-token in your request and raises such an exception.

I think you can see relevant code around https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfFilter.java#L113 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.java#L75

So to fix the issue just **increase your session timeout**. (Timeout of only 1 minute seems incredibly strict to me. I haven't seen anything less than 10 minutes in real life even in "secure" places and typically much more.)

Comment: So, even if I set it for 10 minutes, and a user comes back after 2 days, still this "Remember me" functionality wouldn't work. right ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh, I'm not sure I get your question. "Remember me" and "anti-CSRF" are two separate features with different logic, although both use cookies as part of their implementations. "Anti-CSRF" typically should only block POST requests (and not GET). So if the user just opens a page of your site in a browser, CSRF should let it in, where "remember-me" could do its job. The scenario that might be blocked is if user opens login page, leaves it open for 1 day, comes back and then tries to login. Login should be POST-request and thus might be blocked by expired anti-CSRF token

Comment: @SergGr AFAIK a proper Anti-CSRF solution shouldn't be implemented through cookies. Just to have everything exactly right :)

Comment: @D.Kovács, yes you are right. Actually Spring Security uses HTTP header with fallback to explicit paramater. There might be solutions that use cookies as well but cokies can't be the only way to transfer token as it breaks the whole anti-CSRF idea (because browser will always send them even from different site).

Comment: So, maybe I misunderstood. Isn't it true that "remember-me" should let the user continue work with the application, without any hassle ? Just like facebook, you can close the browser, and even after 3 days, when you navigate to fb website, it still lets you work without logging in.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh, I think I don't understand you. Could you elaborate more details on the scenario that you see some issues with?

Comment: I edited my question and added my security config at the end. I expect the user (who logged in before) to be remembered after that many seconds. Shouldn't it be true ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh It is still not a scenario. Scenario is 1) user does this 2) user does that 3) ... Expected result: Something Actual result: something else.

Comment: Scenario is: User logs in, session time out is 1 minute. the remember-me token validity is 1 week. User comes back, expected is that it should be able to do the regular work without logging in again. right now, I get the error message mentioned in the post: `Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.`

Comment: You again skip the crucial step which is what exactly "do the regular work without logging in again"? Is it GET or POST?

Comment: Both. Just like when the user logs in and he/she can do both without any problem.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh, I already tried to explain it but let's give it one more try. I expect that standard Spring-Security implementation of anti-CSRF doesn't affect any GET requests. So if user gets back and opens new page of your site or does refresh of an existing tab or does navigation inside an existing tab - everything should be fine. As for POST request, anti-CSRF provided by Spring Security will block them if user's session has expired. If you do your POST requests via AJAX, you might handle that case gracefully there. If your site uses old HTTP-form submit logic - it will be blocked

Comment: If that behavior about CSRF is unacceptable, there are other possible implementations of anti-CSRF such as ["Double Submit Cookie"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) or "Encrypted Token Pattern" (see previous link). AFAICS you can configure  Spring-Security to use `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` which seems to be an implementation of  "Double Submit Cookie" strategy

Answer (score 0):

Is this your entire file for spring xml configuration?
 Before starting your xml, try adding this block at start of your xml block that you have provided.

```
<security:http csrf disabled="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login/>

</security:http>
<security:http auto-config:"true"/>
```

This enables the http to adapt property of preventing Request forgery if any claimed from host's IP address.

Since this Security vulnerability is raised, turning it off, will make it unsafe from host's browser, which in this case is you. Doing this is normal, and will unblock you. Althouh i have never seen the issue

```
session not found
```

If request forgery is turned off , it should be good enough to recognize session SID for system.
Also remove this once you add this in xml, you no longer need it as hidden parameter

```
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, the original spring xml configuration is much longer (I will edit the question later and add it there if it helps), as you said it makes the app unsecure. I wonder why this happens at all, and how I can fix it without disabling csrf.

Comment: I just added `web.xml` to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

After one minute when the session expires, it is expected to fail CSRF. What user need to do in that case is refresh the browser before hitting login(or any non-get) request. And if the user doesnt do that you can reload the login page with some frieldly message.

For better user experience, you may try some AJAX based UI technologies, if possible..